# How to echo $variable into text file within a loop

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script in which I have a loop. As the loop goes through different values get assigned to the variable `i` . I want to echo all the values that get `i` gets assigned each time the loop runs, into a text file.

What I am doing is at the moment is:

```
echo " $i " > fail
```

but that only gets me the last value that was assigned to `i` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
echo " $i" >> fail
```

It will append it to the file.

Comment: Works, to be sure -- but unnecessarily inefficient to re-open a file every time you want to write just one line to it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redirecting the individual `echo` to your file, redirect *the entire loop* to the file. This is considerably more efficient, and truncates the file only once, when the loop is started.

```
for i in "${whatever[@]}"; do
   echo "  $i"
done >fail
```

If you don't want to truncate the file at all, of course, you can use `>>fail` in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
echo " $i " >> fail
```

within the loop.

Comment: > fail is what he is doing, which will override the file every time.

Answer (score 0):

`echo " $i" > fail` Will write to the file (overwrite)

`echo " $i" >> fail` Will append to the existing file

Comment: Actually, putting the redirection after the loop often makes more sense. Putting `...command... >>file` inside a loop re-opens the file every time the loop is executed, with the obvious performance/efficiency impact.